# How do I make vim look in a set of directories for a file, if it doesn't exist in the current directory?

Tags: filesystem, load

When I want to edit my `zshrc`, I just type:

```
vim .zshrc
```

Without specifying the full path (`~/.zshrc`), if I am in a different directory, this will instead start a new file. This is very annoying, since I only have one `.zshrc`, in `~`, and only one `vimrc`, in `~/.vim/`. So, how do I get vim to open `~/.zshrc` or `~/.vim/vimrc` when I do `vim .zshrc` or `vim vimrc` in some other directory?

---

While creating some configuration for each individual file is one way, I was thinking of something along the lines of `CDPATH`. `CDPATH` is a variable in some shells that contains a list of paths where `cd` will look for a directory. For example, if I had `CDPATH=:/home/muru`, and I were in *any* directory that doesn't contain a directory named `Desktop`, I could do `cd Desktop` and reach `/home/muru/Desktop`. Simple, elegant, flexible. If `vim` had a `VIMPATH` where it would look for files to edit, that would be the best option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vim's [`'path'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27path%27) option allows you to specify directories which commands like `gf` and `:find` will search for a file.

If you only want this functionality to trigger for a specific set of files, then you could use an autocmd to automatically "redirect" your `:edit` command to the file in one of the `'path'` directories.

```
set path+=~/
function! FindInPath(name)
    let found = findfile(a:name)
    if !empty(found)
        exe 'silent keepalt file '. fnameescape(found)
        edit
    endif
endfunction
autocmd BufNewFile .vimrc,.zshrc nested call FindInPath(expand('<afile>'))
```

This uses the `BufNewFile` autocmd as a trigger for `file not found, so try to find it somewhere else`.  When that situation is detected, use `findfile()` to try to find the file in the `'path'` directories.  If it is found, change the name of the current buffer to that file and re-edit the buffer, otherwise just continue using the new buffer.

The `nested` qualifier is required here since autocmds don't normally nest.  In this case, you do want the typical autocmds to trigger when the `:edit` command opens your file.

Note that this will still create an extra buffer as compared to just editing the file manually.  By the time `BufNewFile` is run, the buffer for the originally specified file name is already created.  Using `:file` to change the name of a buffer creates a new, unloaded buffer with the original name.

If you always want to search in `'path'`, then the autocmd can simply be changed to use the `*` file pattern rather than specifying certain files.

---

Here's an updated version which should match your requirements better.  It uses `:find` to directly open the file instead of setting the buffer name based on the result of `findfile()`.

```
function! FindInPath(name)
    let path=&path
    " Add any extra directories to the normal search path
    set path+=~,~/.vim,/etc
    " If :find finds a file, then wipeout the buffer that was created for the "new" file
    setlocal bufhidden=wipe
    exe 'silent! keepalt find '. fnameescape(a:name)
    " Restore 'path' and 'bufhidden' to their normal values
    let &path=path
    set bufhidden<
endfunction
autocmd BufNewFile * nested call FindInPath(expand('<afile>'))
```

This solves the problem in the previous function where Vim would complain when trying to save the `:file`-named buffer.

Comment: Hmm. `keepalt file` has the same drawback as assigning to `vim.current.buffer.name` - vim warns you that the file already exists when try to save your changes.

Comment: After using this for nearly a year, I have some suggestions: wrap it in `if expand('%') !~ '^[.~]\?/'` ... `endif` so that explicilty specified relative or absolute paths get skipped; and use `silent` instead of `silent!`, because if you open `vim vimrc` in two terminals, the second will wait for input to the usual "file is open elsewhere" warning, but the user has no idea what it's waiting for. I'm not editing it yet, to see if you have better ways to tackle either.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative is to make some commands that will make this easier:

```
command! Evimrc e ~/.vimrc
command! Svimrc sp ~/.vimrc
```

I am using the `E`/`S` pattern that [rails.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails)/[projectionist.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-projectionist) uses.

For more help see:

```
:h :command
:h :e
:h :sp
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not a solution, but it is what I do in order to have easy access to `.vimrc` and `.zshrc`. Personally I think this is pretty neat:

```
map <leader>ev :e ~/.vim/vimrc<cr>
map <leader>ez :e ~/.zshrc<cr>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of `CDPATH`, I wrote a Python-based function to do this (with [help from Matt Boehm](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2205/205)):

```
function LookupFiles ()
    python <<EOF
from os.path import *
from vim import *
current_file = eval ('expand("%")')
current_index = str (current.buffer.number)
PATHS = ['~', '~/.vim', '/etc']

if current_file != '' and  not isfile (current_file):
    for p in map (expanduser, PATHS):
        f = join (p, current_file)
        if isfile (f):          
            command ('bad ' + f)
            command ('bd ' + current_index)
            break
EOF
endfunction

autocmd BufWinEnter * nested call LookupFiles()
```

- I used `BufWinEnter` instead of `BufNewFile` because the latter didn't seem to behave reliably when multiple such filenames where given.
- After a bit of trial and error, I settled on `bad` followed by `bd` as a reliable way to close the buffer opened for the unused file. This still doesn't work when I do `:tabe some-file` (no new tab is opened). However, that's a question for another day.
- Like with `CDPATH`, I can easily add more directories by editing `PATHS`, or making it a Vim-level variable and modifying it.

What the other answers miss, IMO, is that I don't want to create configuration for each *file*, but for each *directory*. I don't care whether I'm opening `fstab` or `vimrc`, I just wanted Vim to search for files in some set of directories if it didn't exist in the current directory. +1 to all of them for the file-specific efforts, though.

Comment: Simply changing my answer to use `*` for the file pattern, rather than specific files, should achieve the same thing and avoids your problem with `:tabe`.

Comment: @jamessan I admit I saw the original autocmd and zoned out. On an unrelated note: the fnameescape might be the solution to another question here, about gvim and remote send.

Answer (score 1):

With [`'user-commands'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#user-commands) and [`'Dictionary'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#Dictionary), we can edit the files without creating a buffer for overriding the file which we want to edit on the buffer.

```
com -nargs=* E call Editfile(<q-args>)
let s:fileLocation = {'vimrc':'~/.vim/', '.zshrc':'~/'}
function Editfile(filename)
    if has_key(s:fileLocation, a:filename)
        exe "e " . fnameescape(s:fileLocation[a:filename].a:filename)
    else
        exe "e " . fnameescape(a:filename)
    endif
endfunction
```

Note that the function `Editfile` does not try to verify its argument. Let's have vim handle all errors like other normal Ex-commands. If the argument is correct then vim starts to edit the file, and if not correct then vim will report errors.

In my opinion, we need not to create a buffer. It has two main drawbacks.

1. The `'not-edited'` flag would be set. As jamessan points out in [his answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2206/8031), if we set the current file name with `:file`command and try to write the file, we will meet the error message `E13: File exists (use ! to override)` This is because vim marks the file as "not edited" when we change the name of the file with `:file` command.
2. We have to try to keep the alternate file name with `:keepalt` command. When we try to edit vimrc while editing 'foo.bar', we expect to the alternate file name should be 'foo.bar'. But if we creates a buffer and change the name, the alternate file name becomes not the "foo.bar" but the buffer's old name 'vimrc'. Even worse, the old buffer will be left as `unlisted-buffer` or `inactive-buffer`. That's why we should use `:keepalt` command in order to keep the alternate file name as we expect and set the `bufhidden` option to be `wipe` to wipe out the old buffer.

If the capital letter in the command name (all user-defined commands should start with capital letter) does not concern us, it would be better to use it. Because it does not create a buffer, we are free of burden for managing the buffer. Just pass the file name to vim and see how vim handles it.