# Why don't I get syntax highlighting when I open a file in an autocmd?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, vimscript, autocmd

While trying to devise a solution to [How do I make vim look in a set of directories for a file, if it doesn't exist in the current directory?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2009/205), I have got so far using Python:

```
function LookupFiles ()
    python <<EOF
from os.path import *
from vim import *
current_file = eval ('expand("%")')
PATHS = ['~', '~/.vim', '/etc']

if not isabs (current_file):
    for p in map (expanduser, PATHS):
        if isfile (join (p, current_file)):
            current.buffer.name = join (p, current_file)
            break
EOF
endfunction

autocmd BufNewFile * call LookupFiles() | e
```

Simply assigning a path to `buffer.name` doesn't cause it to load that file. So I had to call `:edit` manually, which tried both with `vim.command('e')` and the `| e` that you see now. However, for a file opened this way, syntax highlighting isn't present (as well as other plugin effects, from what I can tell). If I manually do `:e` again, everything becomes all right. Why is this, and how can I use Python to correctly open the file? I'd rather not open another buffer unnecessarily, but if that's the case, so be it.

---

Assigning to `current.buffer.name` has its own problem: even though vim can load the buffer just fine with `e`, Vim continues to see it as an entirely new file, and attempts to write through a warning that the file already exists. So I adapted to this version:

```
function LookupFiles ()
    python <<EOF
from os.path import *
from vim import *
current_file = eval ('expand("%")')
current_index = str (current.buffer.number)
PATHS = ['~', '~/.vim', '/etc']

if current_file != '' and  not isfile (current_file):
    for p in map (expanduser, PATHS):
        f = join (p, current_file)
        if isfile (f):          
            command ('bad ' + f)
            command ('bd ' + current_index)
            break
EOF
endfunction
```

The problem of syntax highlighting and other plugin effects still show with this method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [`:help autocmd-nested`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd-nested):

```
By default, autocommands do not nest.  If you use ":e" or ":w" in an
autocommand, Vim does not execute the BufRead and BufWrite autocommands for
those commands.  If you do want this, use the "nested" flag for those commands
in which you want nesting.  For example: >
  :autocmd FileChangedShell *.c nested e!
The nesting is limited to 10 levels to get out of recursive loops.
```

In your case, instead of this line:

```
current.buffer.name = join (p, current_file)
```

You should say:

```
vim.command("edit " + join(p, current_file))
```

And to have the syntax highlighting work, you need to update your autocmd to read:

```
autocmd BufNewFile * nested call LookupFiles()
```

Comment: Actually, `nested` is a part of the autocmd, not a modifier for an ex command.  The autocmd needs to change to `autocmd BufNewFile * nested call LookupFiles() | e`

Comment: @jamessan That's what I understood of the help text and used. I accepted assuming this usage also works.

Comment: whoops, I'll revise my comment. Should have read the docs more closely.