# configure vim to process argv and understand filename:linenumber

Tags: navigation

Does `vim` expose an api for manipulating `argv` before the "main program" looks at it?

I want to be able to use the syntax:

```
$ vim /path/to/my/file:100
```

and have it mean the same thing as

```
$ vim +100 /path/to/my/file
```

if `/path/to/my/file:100` does not itself exist.

I can potentially see writing a wrapper script that does something like the example below, but I would really prefer to keep the logic inside my `.vimrc` if possible.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @args;

foreach my $x (@ARGV) {
    my $candidate = (not (-f $x)) and ($x =~ /:/);
    if ($candidate) {
        my ($path, $linum) = split /:/, $x, 2;
        push @args, ("+" . $linum, $path);
    } else {
        push @args, $x;
    }
}

exec "vim", @args;
```

Comment: I found some plugins which might work [File-line](https://github.com/bogado/file-line) and [vim-fetch](https://github.com/kopischke/vim-fetch). I haven't tried any of these plugins so I can not give a recommendation, but vim-fetch has documentation, so I would start there.

Comment: Related: [How do I make vim look in a set of directories for a file, if it doesn't exist in the current directory?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2009/205), [Setting a default file extension](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6665/205)

Comment: Note: Vim 8.1.2233 adds the `v:argv` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a dirty function for doing this for you:

```
au BufNewFile * nested call ReadFile()

func! ReadFile()
  let l:filename = expand('%:p')
  if l:filename =~ ':\d\+$'
    let l:number = matchstr(l:filename, ':\zs\d\+$')
    let l:filename = matchstr(l:filename, '^[^:]*')
    execute 'bd |  e! '. l:filename
    call cursor(l:number, 1)
  endif
endf
```

This is not beatiful and has some downfalls, but could get you started.

Credits to muru for the nested modifier!

Comment: This is indeed a little bit more complex as we may want to jump to a buffer already opened, we need to apply `ftdetect` after the `:edit`. BTW, I don't remember why, I actually have a [`keepalt e`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/plugin/fixfilename.vim#L38).

Comment: Aah here comes @lucHermitte again. Sorry was a bit in a hurry, wasn't the last version. I do not think that `keepalt` is needed here, since i delete the "wrong" buffer (Or maybe i misunderstood something).  I didn't really understand what you are saying in the first part. As far as I understand it, the `do BufRead` will trigger the `ftdetect`, as always I would be thankfully to hear where I am wrong ;-)
(This seems to make no problems with opening already open buffers...)

Comment: Maybe use a nested autocmd, instead of manually calling `do BufRead`?
 See https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2195/205

Comment: @muru that is great, thank you very much. I've searched for something like this.

Comment: Also: I'd use `:\d\+$` to ensure the line number is at the end of the string, just in case we get an argument like `foo:1.bar:10`, and use `^.*\ze:` to get the filename

Comment: @muru thank you I was aware of that, but I thougth thats a job for the person who asked (detail work). But since you guys are giving me great tips here, i will gladly keep my answer updated. Thank you again I really appreciate learning new things (okay i "think" I allready heard of the `$` regex, but you know what i mean =)

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo, last I checked with my code, the filetype wasn't detected without an explicit `filetype detect`. It seems it was because I was delaying the change of name to the `BufEnter` that follows the `BufNewFile`. Why did I do that? I can remember. May be in order to prevent template expander plugins to import skeletons -- as I observe this problem when I'm listening only for `BufNewFile`... I should have documented what I was doing... :(